# jQuery on click triggering after second click on dynamic elements

Tags: jquery

I m using ajax to include list elements with `select_class` class to a regular `<ul>`. From what I read online, I need to use `on` to be able to add functionality to them. So I tried the following:

```
(function(jQuery) {    
    jQuery(document).on("click", ".select_class", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
       alert("hi");  
    });
})(jQuery);



jQuery(document).on('click', ".select_class", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

alert("hi");

});
```

But they both trigger on second click ...

edit ... my mistake. They're not `li`s. They're `a` in `li`. Like so:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#" class="select_class">something1</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="select_class">something1</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="select_class">something1</a></li>
</ul>
```

Now all of the `select_class` elements require two clicks to trigger the `alert`.

Comment: That is because you are doing it twice.

Comment: no no ... you misunderstood me. I don't use both of them at the same time.

Comment: Can you provide a simple html structure that reproduces the issue you are seeing? Replace ajax with a setTimeout or something.

Comment: See my edit. I don't really understand what you mean by reproducing the issue ... the issue is that the alert requires two clicks to trigger.

Comment: How are you loading your dynamic elements? The problem is likely that you are adding the event listener (aka .on) before the elements exist.

Comment: @ciprian - I mean reproducing the situation where the alert requires two clicks to trigger. Here is a jsfiddle of your post http://jsfiddle.net/7ed564p0/ . Note that the first click causes both alerts to trigger. Can you show the situation in which *the alert requires two clicks to trigger* so that this question is answerable ?

Comment: @Cheruvian your question made me look at how the data was being loaded.  I had e.preventDefault(); and return false; defined. Deleted the return false and everything works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my situation,

`e.preventDefault();` and `return false;` were both defined. That's what was causing the error.

Answer (score -1):

You assign an on click event twice.  You might want to look into using .off() to remove listener and then add it again.
http://api.jquery.com/off/